# Selenium - How to select item from div drop down list?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select the second option from the div drop down via python/selenium. The code below is what I have so far.  The first line opens the drop down and works.  The second line attempts to select the 2 option and click it.  I have tried "2", "22", and "Option-22" but none seem to work.

Sample Python Selenium Code

```
#opens drop down
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[@id='Account']").click()

#selects item from dropdown
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[@id='Account']/option[22]").click()
```

Error Message:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[@id='Account']/option[22] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/*[@id='Account']/option[22]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Sample HTML Code:

```
<div id="Account" class="">
                                    <select>
                                                <option selected="" value="11">Option-11</option>
                                                <option value="22">Option-22</option>
                                                <option value="33">Option-33</option>
                                    </select>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath you want is:

`"//*[@id='Account']//option[@value='22']"`

Or you can use the following CSS Selector:

`'#Account option[value="22"]'`

Or with [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), you can do the full select option in one line:

`self.select_option_by_text("#Account select", "Option-22")`

(Full disclosure: I maintain SeleniumBase)